# Symfony rendering templates from ajax

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I have the following ajax I call:

```
$('.checkbox').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: '/loadProducts',
                data: {},
                success: function(response) {
                    $('.js-products').html(response);
                }});
            return false;
        });
```

Now when I call my endpoint loadProducts, I wants to get products, render a product template(s) and return all of them.

In my endpoint I could do this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/loadProducts", name="loadProducts")
 */
public function loadProducts() {
    /* @var \AppBundle\Service\ProductService $productService */
    $productService = $this->get('app.product');

    $products = $productService->getProducts();

    $productItems = [];
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $productItems = $this->render('home/productItem.html.twig', [
            'product' => $product
        ]);
    }

    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $response->setContent(json_encode($productItems));
    return $response;
}
```

But that only renders one product. How could I return rendering multiple product.html.twig files? (apart from creating a new template that renders all)

Comment: And what is about your php ?

Comment: I specified my endpoint, thats basically how it is, but that renders one product, how would i render many

Comment: Think like this: One request is one response. That response can contain HTML (I think that is what you want). In the HTML you can render multiple (product-)<div>'s. Any with their own image, price and description. In Symfony you can render ONE response too. In basic you render the HTML with ONE twig template but in that template you could use a for loop to render multiple of the same content. in that loop you could include an other template too.

Comment: that is, but im wondering if there is a way in symfony to render a bunch of templates at once and then all at once render the response html

Comment: Not directly. I give you an answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

You will get something like this. Your action will start to render products.html.twig which have a loop that renders multiple times product.html.twig

## products.html.twig

```
{% extends base_template %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        {% for product in products %}
            <div class="col-md-3">
                {% include 'shop/product.html.twig' %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

## product.html.twig

```
<div class="product">
    <img src="somesource.jpg">
    <div class="description">
        <h3>{{ product.name }}</h3>
        <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That i what I have so far but now I want to render more products by clicking on a button. This button does a ajax request to the endpoint to get more products (loadMore) and then renders the results. What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: With the same principle. It is a bit like pagination then because you have to keep track on the amount of rendered products. Actually only your query will change:  return

 $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('...')
        ->setMaxResults(5)
        ->setFirstResult(10)
        ->getResult();

Comment: And use JQuery .append to append the html in the products container. http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: yes but how do i render the result, i cant render it in ajax, so i need to render first in the endpoint and output the result, but how do i render multiple products at once